# Writing a list that displays 15 approximations of pi

Tags: python-3.x

Below I have posted a picture of the task which I want to solve. There I need to show 15 approximations of this number list ([here is the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BpyC.jpg)):

So far I have the following code:

```
p=3
for i in range(15):
    if (i+1) %2==0:
        p= p-(4/((2+2*i)*(3+2*i)*(4+2*i)))
    else:
        p= p+(4/((2+2*i)*(3+2*i)*(4+2*i)))
        
print(p)
```

However it just gives me the 15th result. Can someone please help me?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code, errors or assignments when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable that is uptaded at every iteration. You need to store the desired values in a list or something, like:

```
p=3
my_pis = []
for i in range(15):
    if (i+1) %2==0:
        p= p-(4/((2+2*i)*(3+2*i)*(4+2*i)))
    else:
        p= p+(4/((2+2*i)*(3+2*i)*(4+2*i)))
    my_pis.append(p)

        
print(my_pis)
```